# mysql table version difference

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table (MyISAM), called bla. The Version is 9 (mysql4)
Using a mysql5-server I did an alter table (add column, delete the same column). This is a simple trick to upgrade the table Version.
As shown by mysql:

```
$ echo "show table status from mydb like 'bla'\G" | mysql -p | grep Version
Enter password: 
        Version: 10
```

Normally the unix file command gives the same result, i.e. for another "altered" table:

```
file bla_ok.frm
bla_ok.frm:  MySQL table definition file Version 10
```

But for some "altered" tables (like bla) the file command still gives Version 9 while the above mysql command gives version 10

```
file bla.frm:
bla.frm: MySQL table definition file Version 9
```

Someone has a clue?